# Manage immutable fields in Kubebuilder validating webhook

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, kubebuilder

According to [Kubebuilder documentation](https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/webhook-implementation.html), it is possible to implement immutable fields for a given CRD:

> We separate out ValidateCreate from ValidateUpdate to allow behavior
> like making certain fields immutable, so that they can only be set on
> creation.

Would some of you have some examples or code samples about implementing this?

Comment: Did provided answer help you? Do you need more?

Comment: Please see my comment below Mr Lance answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Kubebuilder example:

```golang
func (r *CronJob) ValidateUpdate(old runtime.Object) error {
    oldCronJob, _ := old.(*CronJob)
    if r.Spec.ImmutableField != oldCronJob.Spec.ImmutableField {
        // accumulate errors
    }
    ...
    // return all errors
}
```

Comment: This code does not build, I have the error: `old.Spec undefined (type runtime.Object has no field or method Spec)`

Comment: updated to get the cronjob struct out of the runtime.object